# django model inheritance - multi table - manual insertion

Tags: django, inheritance, model, insertion

I just redesigned a part of my DB to use multi table inheritance and things are much much easier now!

I do have one question, I am trying to manually insert thousands of rows in my tables and now I cannot figure out how to do it.

e.g.:
Before:

```
class personal(models.Model):
    who = models.CharField...
    stamp = models.DateTime...
    title = models.CharField ...
    descr = models.CharField ...
```

and in python shell:

```
for i in range(1000):
    t=datetime.now()
    e=timedelta(minutes=i)
    entry = personal(who='xyz', stamp=t+e, title='title '+str(i), descr='description for '+str(i)
    entry.save()
```

After:

```
class common(models.Model):
    who ...
    stamp ...

class personal(common):
    title ...
    descr ...
```

and in python shell if I do same thing as above it says personal doesnt have a column named who/stamp

my question: how can I adjust above 'for' to insert multiple rows in my new db?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want abstract model inheritance:

```
class common(models.Model):
    who ...
    stamp ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class personal(common):
    title ...
    descr ...
```

Then above code should work.

EDIT:

For non-abstract inheritance, the insert code should be something like this:

```
for i in range(1000):
    t=datetime.now()
    e=timedelta(minutes=i)
    base = common.objects.create(who='xzy', stamp=t+e)
    entry = personal.objects.create(common_ptr=base, title='title '+str(i), descr='description for '+str(i)
```

Comment: i thought about it, but if i use an abstract model inheritance, then i wont be able to use the common model - i am using the common model to retrieve last ten entries (based on stamp) like this: common.objects.order_by('-stamp')[:10]

Comment: I hope you are aware of the performance implication multi table inheritance (non-abstract model inheritance) has in Django. It is *very* inefficient if used without care.

Comment: thanks for the heads-up ... the only thing im using multi-table inheritance for is this last ten entries code (at least for now) ... i might need to rewrite my code